# Override update method for a queryset - Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-managers

How can we change the default process of the update method for a queryset in django as it does not call save method for each object. And since I have overridden the save method, I need it to be called each time the object is changed.
I looked for [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#modifying-initial-manager-querysets) but this is just for `get_query_set`, Is there is something similar for the update method also.

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me

---

```
class MyQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # here queryset update method overridden
        pass

class NewManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        # this is to use your custom queryset methods
        return MyQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    objects = NewManager()
    myfield = models.SomeTypeOfField(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Do you really need the override for update() at the NewManager level?

Comment: @chad: yes, MyModel.objects.update(**kwargs) actually uses method defined in NewManager and MyModel.objects.filter(**kwargs).update(**kwargs) uses the one defined in MyQuerySet

Comment: Actually maybe it depends on the Django version being used?  The source code for the update() function for manager classes is just `return self.get_query_set().update(*args, **kwargs)`.  So if you want both `filter().update()` and `objects.update()` to behave the same, looks like you just need to override it at the queryset level (unless I'm misunderstanding something).

Comment: @Chad: you are correct. Update method is only defined for querysets only and yes manage update method call the update method at queryset level