# Related models update on model field change

Tags: python, django

What is the most proper way to trigger update of related models, when one of the fields of parent model is changed? I have this set of models:

```
class ActivityObject(models.Model):
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class ActivityJob(models.Model):
    activity_object = models.ForeignKey(
        ActivityObject,
        related_name='activity_jobs',
    )
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

so if I set `ActivityObject.is_deleted = True` on some instance all I want is that all related instances of `ActivityJob` also changed field `is_deleted` to `True`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding save() will work:

```
class ActivityObject(models.Model):
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ActivityObject, self).save(args, kwargs)
        if self.is_deleted:
            for job in self.activity_jobs:
                job.is_deleted = True
                job.save()
```

Just guessing here, but if the real purpose of this is to delete `ActivityJob`s when related `ActivityObject`s are deleted, then you can just go ahead and delete the `ActivityObject`. Django's default behavior will remove all the `ActivityJob`s connected to it.

If you want to perform some other action when deleting, use Django's  [pre_delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#pre-delete) or [post_delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#post-delete) signals, which will call a function you define before/after deleting objects of the type you specify.

EDIT: if you ever use `update()` on querysets dealing with `ActivityObject` and changing `is_deleted`, you can either ensure that you perform a corresponding `update()` on `ActivityJob`, or you can override `ActivityObject`'s `queryset` functionality like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12819789/6492916) to make it happen automatically.

Comment: What if save() is never called?

Comment: @Brian Can you provide an example where the database table for `ActivityObject` is changed without `save()` being called?

Comment: @Yash Tewari I think this is the most suitable solution in my case, thx

Comment: @YashTewari  `save()` is never called if `update()` is used.

Comment: That's right. As I understand it, since `update()` is used to perform changes on `querysets`, it is essentially a way to silently set values across the database. It doesn't trigger any signals, and it obviously doesn't use any `save()` overrides, so anybody using `update()` will in any case have to account for these things.

Any time I use `update()` I have to ensure that it is accompanied by other actions which leave the database in a desirable state. I'll include this in the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django signals' `pre_delete` or `post_delete`. More details and examples are available in the Django Signals [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#post-delete).

Comment: And can i wrap the whole thing with signals kitchen by @transaction.atomic decorator? Because in the upper answer I can wrap the whole `save` method and feel save if the parent object will be changed and related objects won't be changed for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, and I understand that this solution is more flexible in many ways, but it is also much more complicated, including outer dependencies. If I ever need this kind of flexibility, I will use your way of solving that kind of issue. Thanks for spending time on answers :)